# How to check if long list got rendered in React

Tags: reactjs, list, render

Im trying to display a very long list from .json file (2k+ nodes with multiple lines of text). Is there a way to set useState variable after list finishes rendering itself cause useEffect refused to work

```
import React from 'react';
import LongList from './LongList.json';

const LongList = () => {
    const [isLoaded,setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
    }, [setIsLoaded]);

    return (
        <div>
            {LongList.map(element => (
                <div key={element.text}>{element.text}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: What do you mean 'useEffect refused to work'?

Comment: It fires be4 list is fully rendered

Comment: Did any of the solutions below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that by checking the index of the current item:

```
{LongList.map((element, index) => (
    <div key={element.text}>{element.text}</div>
    if(index === LongList.length - 1) {
        // it is loaded
    }
))}
```

Comment: Doesnt this slow the whole rendering process even more?

Comment: Yes, by now is the only solution I have in mind, lets wait for other answers

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `useEffect`. I believe part of the issue you're having is due to using `setIsLoaded` as the second argument to `useEffect`. Instead, use `[]`, which tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. More info [in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

Here's an example, with a console log in the `useEffect` callback showing it's only run once.

```js
const data = Array.from(Array(10001).keys());

const LongList = ({data}) => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Height: ', containerRef.current.clientHeight);
    setHeight(containerRef.current.clientHeight);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Height: {height}</div>
      <div ref={containerRef}>
        {data.map(element => (
          <div key={element}>{element}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<LongList data={data} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```